# How can I configure sails-neo4j adapter?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sails.js

I'm trying to create a simple web app using sailsjs. I'd like to use a neo4j database and I've found only this adapter: https://github.com/natgeo/sails-neo4j/

I try to add the adpter configuration in connection.js using mostly of default value (as I've a default installation):

```
neo4jServer: {
adapter: 'sails-neo4j'
//protocol: 'http://',
//port: 7474,
//host: 'localhost',
//base: '/db/data/',
//debug: false }
```

and specifing it in my model.js file:

```
connection: 'neo4jServer',
```

but I've this error (not so explicit..) if I try to lift up the server (I don't have any logic yet, I only created a couple of model using api generation):

```
C:\WS\SAILS\testProject\node_modules\sails-neo4j\lib\connection.js:15
      throw err;
      ^     Error
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\WS\SAILS\testProject\node_modules\sails-neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-js\lib\Neo4jApi.js:227:13)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Does anyone use it? How can be configured in order to make it works? I'm using sailsjs 0.11.3

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? Do you have authentication enabled for Neo4j? You might need to specify the username/password for Neo4j in the config or disable authentication.

Comment: I'm using neo4j 2.3.1, with user/password. I've tried to add "user" and "password" on the connection configuration but I'm not sure these are the correct keyword as I have not seen any of these in the source. Anyway I obtain the same error.

Comment: Try specifying user/password in the host config property: `host: 'user:password@localhost'` or disable authentication by setting `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in conf/neo4j-server.properties` to see if this is the issue

Comment: Both ways solve the problem. Now the server lift up correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I moved this info into an answer so it's clear your issue was addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using authentication with Neo4j, be sure to specify the credentials. You can do this in the `host` property of the config object for the sails adapter (Neo4j uses Basic Authentication):

```
neo4jServer: {
  adapter: 'sails-neo4j'
  protocol: 'http://',
  port: 7474,
  host: 'username:password@localhost',
  base: '/db/data/',
  debug: false 
}
```

or disable Neo4j authentication by setting `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in conf/neo4j-server.properties